# How do I create a macro for property extensions

Tags: macros, haxe

I'd like to write my own macro for creating property like objects in Haxe.
This question is not so much about properties but more about writing macros.
(probably NME has already a macro for that).

having this class in haxe

```
class Foo {
    @:property var bar:String;
}
```

I like this to be expanded into

```
class Foo {
    private var bar:String;

    public function setBar(_val:String):void {
        this.bar = _val;
    }

    public function getBar():String {
        return this.bar;
    }
 }
```

I read the corresponding docs but honestly I find them very confusing.

thanks

Answer (score 1):

You might want to take a look at how tinkerbell resolves the same issue: https://github.com/back2dos/tinkerbell/wiki/tink_lang#wiki-accessors

Comment: Hi Franco, I had a look into it - alas its pretty confusing.
I had also a look https://github.com/back2dos/tinkerbell/blob/master/src/tink/lang/macros/PropBuilder.hx but it makes so many things that it really doesnt answer the more basic questions I have. for example why do all the tinkerbell classes implement "tink.lang.Cls" or how does the macro system react to "@:xxx"? why does that trigger the macro-system?
Also what is the association between "@:prop" and the class PropBuilder. I couldnt find any information to this

Answer (score 0):

This [Type Builder example](http://haxe.org/manual/macro-type-building.html) (pasted below for reference, but there's better description at the link) found in the [Haxe Manual](http://haxe.org/manual/) is a nice, simple example of adding a function to a Class.

Adding a property would be much the same. I added a trace(field) loop to help get a feel for how they're defined:

**Main.hx**

```
@:build(TypeBuildingMacro.build("myFunc"))
class Main {
  static public function main() {
    trace(Main.myFunc); // my default
  }
}
```

**TypeBuildingMacro.hx**

```
import haxe.macro.Context;
import haxe.macro.Expr;

class TypeBuildingMacro {
  macro static public function build(fieldName:String):Array<Field> {
    var fields = Context.getBuildFields();
    for (field in fields) { trace(field); }
    var newField = {
      name: fieldName,
      doc: null,
      meta: [],
      access: [AStatic, APublic],
      kind: FVar(macro : String, macro "my default"),
      pos: Context.currentPos()
    };
    fields.push(newField);
    return fields;
  }
}
```

Note that Main.hx must invoke the macro with the `@:build` metadata, so the compiler knows to run the macro (which adds the function) before processing the Main class itself.